# if stmt->execute not going into else statement when false

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here ...

This php runs a select query and then returns the result as a json encode. 
It would seem the `if($stmt->execute())`is not working correctly, if I put in an incorrect username and password I am getting [] instead of the "Incorrect email or password!", its not going into the else statement.

```php
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

//check user exists
$qry = "SELECT u.uid, u.name, u.email, u.registration_date, u.updated_at, d.device_name, d.device_registration_date
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN devices d
ON d.parent_id = u.uid
WHERE u.email = ? AND u.password = ? ";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($qry);
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $email, $password);
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {     
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["device"][]=$row; 
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // user not found
    $response["fail"] = 0;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Incorrect email or password!";
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;
}
$stmt->close();
```

EDIT !

I tried checking for rows , but this gives me a new problem, the below results in
 Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array()

```php
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($qry);
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $email, $password);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->store_result();
if ($stmt->num_rows >= 0) {
    $result = $stmt->get_result();  
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Try changing >=0 change that to >=1 .... like my answer below does.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to get it to work by running a separate query if the first returned rows ...

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    //check user exists
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? AND password = ? ";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($qry);
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $email, $password);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $resultRows = $stmt->num_rows;
    $stmt->free_result();
    if($resultRows >= 1){

        $qry = "SELECT u.uid, u.name, u.email, u.registration_date, u.updated_at, d.device_name, d.device_registration_date
        FROM users u
        LEFT JOIN devices d
        ON d.parent_id = u.uid
        WHERE u.email = ? AND u.password = ? ";
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($qry);
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $email, $password);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();

        while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
        {       
                $response["success"] = 1;
                $response["device"][]=$row;

        }
        echo json_encode($response);


    }
    else {
        // user not found
        $response["fail"] = 0;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Incorrect email or password!";
        echo json_encode($response);
        exit;
    }
    $stmt->close();
```

Comment: lol this is basically a copy of my answer... you even used my $resultRows

Answer (score 2):

It's returning like that simply because the statement was still successful, even if it didn't return any rows. An unsuccessful query is when there's an error in your SQL, for example.

Instead, you need to count the number of returned rows.

Comment: Thats what I was trying first, using if ($stmt->num_rows != 0){ ... but then the fetch_array wont work for some reason

Comment: It appears you need to use `$stmt->store_result()` first to be able to do that. Have a look at the bottom of this page: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Comment: Still getting "Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array"

Comment: Try taking out the `$stmt->fetch()`. Also, check that `$result` isn't NULL.

Comment: same, $stmt->get_result(); seems to fail after $stmt->store_result();
        if ($stmt->num_rows >= 0){ ... if I remove this, the get_result and array work (but then I have original issue)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

//check user exists
$qry = "SELECT u.uid, u.name, u.email, u.registration_date, u.updated_at, d.device_name, d.device_registration_date
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN devices d
ON d.parent_id = u.uid
WHERE u.email = ? AND u.password = ? ";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($qry);
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $email, $password);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_results();

$resultRows = $stmt->num_rows;
$stmt->free_result();

if($resultRows >= 1){
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["device"][]=$row;

    echo json_encode($response);
}
else {
    // user not found
    $response["fail"] = 0;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Incorrect email or password!";
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;
}
$stmt->close();
```